# Carga de Datos Pagina Web Angular

Tags: angular, spring, carga

Tengo una pagina web con **Angular** desde el **front** y **Spring** desde el **back**, el problema que tengo es que al **cargar** la web **se muestra el front y despues de 1-2 segundos se muestran los datos** que recibe mediante las peticiones al servidor, lo que quiero hacer es que al cargar la web **se muestre directamente los datos junto al front** aunque tarde mas en cargar ya que como esta ahora queda bastante mal.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

**Ejemplo:**

Al cargar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Despues de 1-2 segundos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

simplemente debes usar una variable que te indicará si el contenido ya está disponible. Antes de hacer la llamada le das como valor false, cuando recibas la respuesta le das el valor true.
Imagina que la variable se llama contenidoDisponible, el html sería así:

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="!contenidoDisponible" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
<div *ngIf="contenidoDisponible">Aqui iria el contenido</div>
```

Mientras el contenido no esté disponible muestra un progress-bar.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, pero buscaba algo mas automatico, que detectase si ya tiene la petición igual de tener que hacer un spinner y hacerlo con cada componente. Pero en el caso de que no se pueda probaré con el spinner, gracias.

Comment: @DavVR Complementando la respuesta de Marc, puedes utilizar un `interceptor` para detectar todas las peticiones http que realices y dentro de este, mostrar y ocultar el spinner.

Comment: Si, podría usar un interceptor, se podría comunicar con el componente padre mediante un servicio e ir mostrando un spinner cada vez que hay una petición. El problema es que si en algún momento quieres mostrar una parte de la página mientras se carga otra no se podría, ¿no?